# Update/Edit site users with Active_admin trouble

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I Have authentication from scratch (without devise, oauth gem)
User has email, login and password_digest (has_secure_password in model)
So, I just wanna update users from active_admin panel, but it takes all BD Columns to Edit form and I have "Can't mass-assign protected attributes: password_digest"
How can I exclure some fields (as password) from user edit form of active_admin and just updates not protected attrs?

```
error text:
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in Admin::UsersController#update
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: password_digest
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by adding a silmple block to user model in /admin dir:

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "Details" do
    f.input :login
    f.input :email
    f.input :password
  end
  f.buttons
end
```

Now i can edit my users and put unencrypted passwords.